# Format a property before displaying it

Tags: ember.js

Hello StackOverflow experts,

I would like to know if it would be possible to use Ember.js' computed properties to modify the value of the property before returning to whatever object requests it.

Imagine this simple example:
I have a User object with mail property
When I set the property, I want the email address to change from first.last@example.com to first.last@anotherexample.com, then return it

When I request the property ( via User.get ) I want to get the modified property back.

I think it should be pretty simple by utilising another 'helper' property, like formatted_mail, where I would store and retrieve the formatted value, but I wonder if something like this can be done without additional model properties.

So far, I have this coffescript code, but I always get 'undefined' when reading the property, even though I set it before, so I suspect the value does not get saved by Ember anywhere:

```
mail: ( ( key, value ) ->
    if arguments.length == 1
        return this.get 'mail'
    else
        return value.split( '@' )[0] + '@anotherexample.com'
).property 'mail'
```

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: try with handlebars helper, something like `{{formatEmail mail}}`

Comment: Hi ManoHaran, that seems like a way as well, but I feel this modification is really tied to my model's logic and I would prefer for this to happen on the model object, not on the presentation layer. Thanks for suggestion, though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to solution.

As computed properties are always cached by default in Ember (you could disable this behaviour using `.volatile()`), you do not have to specify what to do when `arguments.length` is 1, except if you want to specify a default value.

So here it should looks like:

```
App.User = Ember.Object.extend({
  mail: function(key, value) {
    if (arguments.length === 2) {
      return value.split('@')[0] + "@tieto.com";
    }
    return null;
  }.property()
});
```

The `return null` just specify the default value.

When you set the `mail` property, it will cache the returned value and always returns it without recomputing this property.

Note that you can do that only because the `mail` property does not depend on other properties. If you were declaring it with `.property('anotherProperty')`, the `mail` property will be recomputed any time `anoterProperty` changes. So in the example above it will reset it to `null`.

You can try it [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lcoq/vBH7L/).

Comment: Hi, this works as expected. It turned out after some debugging that I was accessing that computed property using user.mail, instead of user.get('mail') and that, of course, did not help. Thanks for your assistance!